# Javascript function increase/decrease cellValue

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have made two functions that will upon activating, will increase or decrease the cell value by 1

I added a condition, that if the cellValue greater than / lesser than -1 and 3 respectably the function will not run.

I tried two ways of going around this issue, however both of them are giving me issues.

```
function increment(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cellValue; 
 cellValue = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var range = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var value = range.getValue(); 

if (cellValue < 3) {
range.setValue(value + 1);
}
}
```

---

```
function increment(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cellValue; 
cellValue = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var range = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var value = range.getValue(); 

if (cellValue < 3) return;
range.setValue(value + 1);

}
```

The first function uses

```
if (cellValue < 3) {range.setValue(value + 1);
```

however the function does not do anything, I tried <= and the function still does not do anything.

The second uses a

```
if (cellValue < 3) return;
```

check before adding the value. This formula adds 1 everytime I press the function, it keeps adding adding a number

Did I do something wrong with appointing the cellValue? I am very new to Javascript and I'm learning it with the spreadsheet

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may need `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in the following line.

```
var cellValue; 
cellValue = sheet.getRange("AM39");
```

Compare it with the other piece of code you wrote:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var value = range.getValue();
```

What happens, is that cellValue is a range, while value is the actual value of the cell, so doing `if (cellValue < 3) {`, and that (I tested it) causes the error.

**To solve**

just change `cellValue = sheet.getRange("AM39");` to `cellValue = sheet.getRange("AM39").getValue();`

Edit: Problem with a second solution is that `return` immediately abrupts execution of the function. My advice is for you to read [this.](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
function increment() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()[0].getRange("AM39"),
    n = range.getValue();
if (n > -1 && n < 3) return;
range.setValue(parseInt(n) + 1);
}
```